# Is there a place online to look for lattice structures and constants for most (if not all) of the crystals constituted of single element?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, crystals

For example, if I want to look for lattice structure and constants (unit cell side lengths, angles) of the Bismuth crystal, where should I go for? It is more important for me to know the cell constants (lengths, angles) then the lattice type.

It will be great if the lattice/unit cell constants are given in well-understood manner, i.e. easy to know which side lengths/angles correspond to which.

Answer (score 1):

The crystal sturcture of organic, inorganic, metal-organics compounds and minerals can be found here:

http://www.crystallography.net/cod/

In case you are interested in 2D materials; there is a nice data base including electronic, vibronic and mechanical properties of all sorts of layered 2D materials which can be found here:

https://cmr.fysik.dtu.dk/c2db/c2db.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://www.webelements.com/

In general you could just look up what you need, but for single elements there's that site. For semiconductors I know of this: http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/index.html